# Create database in plesk api

Tags: php, api, plesk

I am trying to get the id of a just created subscription in order to use in the creation of a database. However I can't get the id and in var_dumb($info) it returns false. Here is my code:

```
$paramsPleskSubscription = array(
'domain_name'=>$company.'.example.com',
'username'=>$email,
'password'=>$password,
'ip_address'=>'99.99.99.99',
'owner_id'=>$clientPleskId,
'service_plan_id'=>$service_plan_id,
);

$requestSub = new \pmill\Plesk\CreateSubscription($config, $paramsPleskSubscription);
$info2 = $requestSub->process();
var_dump($info2);
$subscriptionId=$requestSub->id;
echo "subscription:".$subscriptionId; //it returns nothing
```

I am using this library https://github.com/pmill/php-plesk.
If there is anyotherway to get the id of a newly created subscription I ll be happy to implement it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may happens because of request has failed by some reason.

You can control which actual request was send to Plesk and which response was provided if you enable debug log in /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/panel.ini:

```
[debug]

; Enable debug mode (do not use in production environment)
enabled = on

[log]

; Log messages verbosity level (from 0 to 7)
; 0 - only critical errors, 7 - all including debug messages, default - 3
filter.priority = 7
```

Now you can see requests and responses in `/usr/local/psa/admin/logs/panel.log`

Comment: I receive the following in the log file as a final response:
      `<result>
        <status>error</status>
        <errcode>1019</errcode>
        Incorrect name example32.com. This domain name already exists.` But ofcourse it is the first time i create the domain...